# returning multiple objects from a function [C#],[ASP.NET Core]

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, web-applications

I have a function which is checking if the user has correct role assigned to it.
So if the user doesn't have the correct role I'm returning Forbid() so it can be redirected to login page.
But now I want to have a toster message displaying the appropriate message why it is being redirected.
So I looking for way how can I display that toast message and redirect to login page.

Comment: Can you share the cost of function and how is it being used?

Answer (score 0):

```
[FunctionName("SampleResponse")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> SampleResponse(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
 
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
 
    string name = data.name; // get name from dynamic/JSON object
 
    if (name == null)
    {
        // Return a 400 bad request result to the client with additional information
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name in the request body");
    }
 
    // Return a 200 OK to the client with additional information
    return new OkObjectResult($"{name} exists");
}
```

your UI should check the response message, then perform the redirect.